# Decreasing memory consumption during Import

Tags: list-manipulation, import, memory

We have 70 `.dat` (text) files each of which contains a column of numbers. This column can be assumed as a vector obtained from another program. The `Length` of each column is `1.67772*10^7`. We wish to import them (from `1` to `70` text files) in Mathematica notebook in order to apply some procedures.

```
Do[
    vector[i] = 
     Flatten@Import["obtainedvector" <> ToString[i] <> ".dat", "Table"]
      , {i, 1,70}];
```

But when the importing process reaches `i=20`, Mathematica does not continue the importing process, and every thing in Ram vanishes as if nothing has been done previously!! There are two solutions: 1- A way to importing faster without encountering the problem (to which I am not familiar ) 2- There is not any necessity to import all vectors and we can do the procedures considered in a Mathematica notebook directly using a text file and without importing them (unfortunately I do not know its details).

I would be so grateful if someone helps me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html). It's lower-level, faster, and less memory intensive.

@AlexyPopkov points out that we can do this:

```
ReadList["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", {Number, Number}] // 
  MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

{0.930234, 105096624}
```

And it's even better than my original proposal with [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html).

```
Export["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 2}], "Table"];

Partition[ReadList["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", Number], 2] === 
 Import["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", "Table"]

True

Partition[ReadList["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", Number], 2] // MaxMemoryUsed

1120728

Import["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", "Table"] // MaxMemoryUsed

5741304
```

By the way, it might make sense to process at the time of import, rather than importing everything then processing. It'll decrease memory usage.

Comment: Very interesting!!

Comment: Your suggested title is very better than mine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With `ReadList["~/Desktop/bleh.dat", {Number, Number}]` you don't need `Partition`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh of course. I always forget the more complex specs. Let me update.

Comment: Because I have just one column I did not considered to {Number, Number} but it is very useful

Comment: @InzoBabaria glad to hear it. The `Read*` functions can be very, very useful.

Comment: Yes, Also, another your comment in which you advised that I should do the process after Reading each elemnt is very efficient.